# ruby on railsでのturbolinksの挙動

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

### 実行環境

- ruby ver3.1.2
- ruby on rails ver6.1.7.3
- node ver16.20.0

### 質問内容

#### 現状

現在、ruby on railsでturbolinksを使った際の挙動に悩んでいます。
トップページとアバウトページを作っており、以下のようなコードを書いています。

top.html.erb

```
<p>top page</p>
<%= link_to 'top page', homes_top_path %>
<%= link_to 'about page', homes_about_path %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
    let x = 'test1';
    let y = 'test2';
    let z = 'test3';
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    console.log(z);
  });
</script>
```

about.html.erb

```
<p>about page</p>
<%= link_to 'top page', homes_top_path %>
<%= link_to 'about page', homes_about_path %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
    let x = 'test4';
    console.log(x);
  });
</script>
```

この状態でトップページを最初に読み込むと、console上で以下のようになります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

その後、アバウトページにリンクを押して遷移すると、console上で以下のようになります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 実現したいこと

turbolinksを使った画面遷移を行った際、とび先のページに存在するscriptタグのコードのみを実行したいです。
今回の例でいうと、トップページからアバウトページに遷移した際に、console上でtest4だけが表示されるようにしたいです。
turbolinksはソースをキャッシュするというのは何となく知っているのですが、どうすれば上記のことを実現できるのかわかりません。